# Why we use leap second in kernel and NTP?

Tags: kernel, utc, ntp

UNIX timestamp and many libraries don't support leap second. They don't give more attention to it, and many bugs are caused by leap second. So why we use leap second in NTP and kernel? If we just let it be, the one second error will be fixed soon. (Actually the error caused by the hardware is far greater than leap second.)

Answer (score 0):

Time is used in navigation, so small inaccuracies cost big dollars; and over the centuries midnight might become light outside.  The earth rotation around the sun is not constant--leap seconds correct for this.